# What is the answer to this derivative?

Tags: derivatives

This derivative just showed up in a past paper as part of a question, i don't know what to do with it because of the summation etc?? Please help

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial h} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h^n J_n(x)$$

J is just any function of x i think

Comment: Is the sum from -infinity to infinity or 0 to infinity?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{\partial}{\partial h}J_n(x)=0$.

Comment: If it all works well, this should be $\sum_{\substack{n=-\infty}\\{n\ne0}}^\infty nh^{n-1}J_n(x)$, but whether this is indeed the case, depends on what the $J_n$ are, what interval this is computed over, etc.

Comment: I would expect $J_n$ to be a Bessel function. They have many sum relations. Your partial becomes $nh^{n-1}$

Comment: "Master, what is the difference between a humanistic, monastic system of belief in which wisdom is sought by means of an apparently nonsensical system of questions and answers, and a lot of mystic gibberish made up on the spur of the moment?"
Wen considered this for some time, and at last said, "A fish!"
And Clodpole went away, satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

If $J_n(x)$ does not depend on $h$, then it's simply:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial h} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty h^n J_n(x)=
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial h} h^n \right) J_n(x)=
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty nh^{n-1}J_n(x)
\end{equation}